# convert HTML string to text node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know this questions has already been asked before but I haven't found a straight answer that could help me.

I'm  trying to convert a previously created string into a Text Node so I can remove it from the DOM with removeChild().

I have this HTML code:

http://prntscr.com/hxf1jw

I want to select the string "Confirm" and remove it. I already select it with firstChild.nodeValue; but when I try to remove it with removeChild(), it says that it is not a node.

So how can I convert that "Confirm" into a text node? I can't use JQuery or any other library.

This is the full code of that event handler:

```
 ul.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
   const checkbox = event.target;
   const checked = checkbox.checked;
   const listItem = checkbox.parentNode.parentNode;
   const confirmed = document.createTextNode('Confirmed');
   const confirm = checkbox.parentNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
   const label = checkbox.parentNode;

   if (checked) {
     listItem.className = 'responded';
     label.insertBefore(confirmed, checkbox);
     label.removeChild(confirm);    //Here is the error
   } else {
     listItem.className = '';
   }
 });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try changing const confirm = checkbox.parentNode.firstChild.nodeValue;   To const confirm = checkbox.parentNode.firstChild;   So you are removing a node and not a string

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath problem solved!! thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome Carlos

Comment: I voted to close as "Off topic -> Cannot reproduce".